# How can I find out the user's city, age and gender?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, visitor-statistic, web-statistics

I have a Google Analytics code on my page, and it somehow finds out user's gender, age and location.
Can I access that data when the user opens the page, and show something like "Hey, that's what Google knows about you: your age, gender and the city"?

I use `analytics.js`, just in case it's important.

Probably analytics.js has some functions in it and I can access it using JavaScript? Or that data could  be found out some other way?

Comment: Google is using profiles that are registered with Google, cookies to see what pages the browser visits etc. to try and figure out age, male or female, interests etc. They do this primarily for targeted ads, but now also to improve analytics data, but I'll bet good money they won't give you that data on a per user basis, only as a general overview in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google doesn't provide this data for individual users. It's only available on an aggregate basis in Analytics reports. They even [apply thresholds](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2954071) to some reports so that individuals can't be identified.

Answer (score 0):

That is the Demographics and Interests Reports you talking about, however they are not yet available in `analytics.js` only the previous version `ga.js`. [(source)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/)

Google has said that `analytics.js` should be getting support for those reports soon.

Using `ga.js` I know you can now call them via the [core reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) but not in real time so don't think you can load them at the same time when a user loads a page.